# C# - Xamarin.Forms - Dependency Service and event

Tags: c#, events, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I would like to be notified with a PropertyChanged event raised from a class `MyClass` implementing an interface `IMyInterface`. The instance of this class is retrieved with `DependencyService.Get<IMyInterface>();`

Now, this is the class (Android project), in which there is a property with a backing field:

```
class MyClass : IMyInterface {

    private bool _isEnabled;
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        private set { _isEnabled = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsEnabled"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public void OnSomethingHappens() { //This method is called when something particular happens
        /* Some code... */
        IsEnabled = true; //The point where the property is changed
        /* ...some other code */
    }
}
```

The interface (Forms project) looks like this:

```
public interface IMyInterface : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /* code relating the interface */
}
```

This interface is implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in order to have the possibility to listen to a property change (as seen in the class above). So far, so good.

The problem is when, in my Forms project, I register an event handler with this:

```
_myService = DependencyService.Get<IMyInterface>();
_myService.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => { /* do stuff */ };
```

But when the property in my implementing class changes, `PropertyChanged` results null, and this means that the event is never fired.

I would like to add a little thing: recently, I experienced that accessing a non-static list property with `DependencyService.Get<IMyInterface>().MyList` was useless, since `MyList` resulted to be of size `0`, even if this list was filled inside the implementing class. I solved this using a static property. Maybe this is related to the issue above.

I would like to understand what I am mistaking in order to have this `PropertyChanged` event working correctly.

Comment: Are you sure you're accessing the same instance of `_myService`, each call to the dependency service is returning a new instance, not a singleton.

Comment: It's what I thought when I encountered that issue with the `List`. Anyway, now I have only one reference to the impementing class. Maybe I should always call `DependencyService.Get<IMyInterface>()` instead (actually, I don't think so)?

Comment: What I would suggest you create a static instance of your dependency call `DependencyService.Get<IMyInterface>();` and use the same instance everytime you need it anywhere this should solve the issue that you currently have.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried using this, but the issue remains. I'm sure that the event subscription is made before the event occurs, but `PropertyChanged` is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to solve this.
Basically, I created a property with a `private static event` backing field, as follows:

```
private static event PropertyChangedEventHandler _propertyChanged;
public PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
{
    get { return _propertyChanged; }
    set { _propertyChanged = value; }
}
```

This way, I could have the following code working properly:

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    _propertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

Infact, `_propertyChanged` was not `null` anymore, since I subscribed to the event with the following code (formally identical to the one posted on my question, with the difference that I used the `PropertyChanged` property backed with the private static field `_propertyChanged`):

```
_myService = DependencyService.Get<IMyInterface>();
_myService.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => { /* do stuff */ };
```

Now I think that this was necessary because I am using `DependencyService`, otherwise, in normal code, this issue should not come out.
Anyway, I am guessing if the idea of having a `EventHandler` property backed with a `private static event` field is a good code practice or just sounds weird. But it works, and it works pretty good.

But, in order to do all of this, I had to change this:

```
public interface IMyInterface : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /* code relating the interface */
}
```

to this:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged { get; set; }
    /* code relating the interface */
}
```

I had  to add that property in `IMyInterface` so that I could access it from my Forms project code.
Moreover, I no more implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, because `INotifyPropertyChanged` asks me to implement the interface with a:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
```

inside my implementing class, but I substituted it with

```
private static event PropertyChangedEventHandler _propertyChanged;
public PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
{
    get { return _propertyChanged; }
    set { _propertyChanged = value; }
}
```

as I exposed above.

Comment: And, by the way, I also changed my private bool field `_isEnabled` (see above in my question) to be `static` since calling `DependencyService.Get<IMyInterface>().IsEnabled` returned me `false` even if the backing field had changed, but now, with static modifier, `DependencyService.Get<IMyInterface>().IsEnabled` returns the correct value.